# How to sum a list of tuples

Tags: scala, sum, tuples

Given the following list of tuples...

```
val list = List((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2))
```

... how do I sum all the values and obtain a single tuple like this?

```
(3, 6)
```

Comment: Note that if you're using Scalaz you automatically get monoid instances for tuples whose elements have monoid instances, so you can just write `list.suml`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the `foldLeft` method. Please look at the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@foldLeft[B]%28z:B%29%28f:%28B,A%29=%3EB%29:B) for more information.

```
scala> val list = List((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2))
list: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,2), (1,2))

scala> list.foldLeft((0, 0)) { case ((accA, accB), (a, b)) => (accA + a, accB + b) }
res0: (Int, Int) = (3,6)
```

Using `unzip`. Not as efficient as the above solution. Perhaps more readable.

```
scala> list.unzip match { case (l1, l2) => (l1.sum, l2.sum) }
res1: (Int, Int) = (3,6)
```

Answer (score 11):

Very easy: `(list.map(_._1).sum, list.map(_._2).sum)`.

Comment: Doesn't this traverse the list twice? Not that efficient then.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using `Monoid.combineAll` from the `cats` library:

```scala
import cats.instances.int._ // For monoid instances for `Int`
import cats.instances.tuple._  // for Monoid instance for `Tuple2`
import cats.Monoid.combineAll

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val list = List((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2))

    val res = combineAll(list)

    println(res)
    // Displays
    // (3, 6)
  }
```

You can see more about this in the [cats documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monoid.html#example-usage-collapsing-a-list) or [Scala with Cats](https://books.underscore.io/scala-with-cats/scala-with-cats.html#summary-1).

Answer (score 1):

answering to this question while trying to understand aggregate function in spark

```
scala> val list = List((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2))
list: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,2), (1,2))

   scala>  list.aggregate((0,0))((x,y)=>((y._1+x._1),(x._2+y._2)),(x,y)=>(x._1+y._2,y._2+x._2))
res89: (Int, Int) = (3,6)
```

Here is the link to the SO QA that helped to understand and answer this [[Explain the aggregate functionality in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240706/explain-the-aggregate-functionality-in-spark/38949457][1])

Answer (score 1):

Scalaz solution (suggestied by Travis and for some reason a deleted answer):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val list = List((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2))
list.suml
```

which outputs

```
res0: (Int, Int) = (3,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a reduce function :

```
val list = List((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2))

val res = list.reduce((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))
```