# How can I add values in key value pairs generated in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

How to add the keys and values separately from the keys and value pairs generated in spark scala?

Given the following input

```
(5,1),(6,1),(8,1)
```

I'd like to get to the following output

```
(19,3)
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myapp").getOrCreate()   
val data = spark.read.textFile(args(0)).rdd  
val result =
  data.map { line => {  
    val tokens = line.split("\t")  
    (Float.parseFloat(tokens(4)),1)  
  }}.
  reduceByKey( _+ _)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data as well?

Comment: Row 1:10-10-2010 Chennai VMall Raju 10,000 
Row 2:10-11-2010 Hyderabad CRMall Ram 5000 and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` or `fold` to get the result, You also need to convert the `token(4)` value to `Int` or any other Numeric type as you need.

```
val result = data.map{line => {  
  val tokens = line.split("\t")  
  (tokens(4).toInt,1)  
}}
```

**Using fold**

```
result.fold((0,0)) { (acc, x) => (acc._1 + x._1, acc._2 + x._2)}
```

**Using reduce**

```
result.reduce((x,y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if I use the above reduce method saveAsTextFile is not working throwing prompt like it is not a member of (Float,Int)

Comment: saveAsTextFile is performed on rdd but you already performed an action with reduce or fold so which gives you (Int, Float)

Comment: Can you explain me how I can save and view the result after fold or reduce?

Comment: Assign it to a variable and print it

Comment: but if we use executable jar like exporting our program into jar and then executing it,then print method will not work right?

Answer (score 0):

`reduceByKey` won't serve your purpose here. Please use `foldLeft`.

Refer [Scala: How to sum a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154736/scala-how-to-sum-a-list-of-tuples) for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myapp").getOrCreate()   
val data = spark.read.textFile(args(0)).rdd  
val result = data.map{line => {  
  val tokens = line.split("\t")  
  (tokens(4).toInt,1)  
}}  
.reduce((l, r) => (l._1+r._1, l._2+r._2))
```

It's possible that a `foldLeft` (as suggested by Vinod Chandak) is more appropriate, but I tend to use `reduce` as I have more experience with it.